# I have 2 transaction one login another one is logout.those login, logout are selenium webdriver sampler.when i try to logout it goes agin login page

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I have to logout the page. When i tried to logout it goes again login page.. I have kept the request as 2 different transaction controller for login and logout because I have to collect the results for login and logout transaction..

Requirement:
Logout page directly not once again going into the login the page

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to provide comprehensive help without seeing your code.

One thing is obvious: [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) creates an instance of [WebDriver](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html) when the thread (virtual user) starts and keeps it until the virtual user is shut down.

So given you only need to perform the logout the [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) code of your 2nd WebDriver Sampler should be just like:

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
def logoutLink = WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath('//a[text()="Logout or whatever text you have"]'))
logoutLink.click()
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

It might also be worth checking [jmeter.log  file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries.